# AS3 Splice(:ed) and wants to "re index"?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, splice

Ok, so I have a array like this.

```
myArray:Array []

myArray.push(Object) // x 4.
```

I have 4 objects in my array. Then I splice the second one. Leaving me with a array that looks like this. 1,3,4. Now... I would like to have this array look like this: 1,2,3. I Would like the 3 & 4 to simple switch place to one less from their own postion.

I know it's possible, I had a friend do it for me some years ago. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to have this array look like this: 1,2,3

So...just `pop()` the last element:

```
myArray:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
myArray.pop();
trace(myArray);  // Prints: 1,2,3
```

> I Would like the 3 & 4 to simple switch place to one less from their own postion.

Umm...that's exactly what deleting the second element already did...

If the end result you want is that the second element be placed *at the end*, that is:

```
Before: [1, 2, 3, 4]  --> After [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Then you can do that in two steps:

```
var spliced = myArray.splice(1, 1); // Remove the second element and return it 
myArray.push(spliced);              // Push it to the end of the array
```

Technically you could do this in one step, since the splice will happen first:

```
myArray.push(myArray.splice(1, 1));
```

Comment: No, maybe I explained badly. Ok, I have a array [Cat, Dog, Mouse, Cow]. If I want to remove Dog, I do myArray.slice(2) right? Then Im left with [Cat, Mouse, Cow] but when I trace my array, it still says 1,3,4? 1 = Cat, 3 = Mouse, 4 = Cow.

Comment: Damn... I forgot to say Im removing a specific one :/

Comment: @user1133188 No, `slice` is different the `splice`. Also, all indexes are 0-based. So to __remove__ the second element, you would call `myArray.splice(1, 1)`, which means "starting at index 1, remove 1 elements". To remove the third element, you would write `myArray.splice(2, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are failing when using splice. splice and slice is different methods for array  slice not changes the original array but returns new array with sliced gap

example

```
var arr:Array = ["Cat","Dog", "Mouse", "Cow"];
trace(arr.slice(1,3));// output : Dog,Mouse
trace(arr.slice(2));//output: Mouse,Cow
trace(arr) //output: Cat,Dog,Mouse,Cow
```

so when you call arr[3] you are getting Cow but your array didnt change at all

splice modifies your original array

```
var arr:Array = ["Cat","Dog", "Mouse", "Cow"];
arr.splice(1,1); // output: 0->Cat,1->Mouse,2->Cow
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your pseudo code ->
Here is the result:

[object Cat],[object Mouse],[object Cow]

There is no index when tracing.. another point, I some code

```
trace(arr[0] , arr[1], arr[2]);
```

And I still get

[object Cat],[object Mouse],[object Cow]

The indexes are fine automatically in AS3.

```
package regression 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Arthur Wulf White
     */
    public class Check_array_index_test_1 extends Sprite
    {

        public function Check_array_index_test_1() 
        {
            var arr: Array = new Array();
            arr.push(new Cat, new Dog, new Mouse, new Cow);
            trace(arr);
            arr.splice(1, 1);
            trace(arr);
                    trace(arr[0] , arr[1], arr[2]);
        }

    }

}

class Cat { }
class Dog { }
class Mouse { }
class Cow {}
```